# Swagger UI not displaying when deploying API on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

Well, I'm using Swagger for my API documentation and it works perfectly in localhost, the problem begins when I host it on the IIS. For somereason it just doesn't work anymore

> localhost:

```
https://localhost:44381/swagger/index.html
```

> api:

```
http://200.155.29.14/SimuladorFrete/Swagger/index.html
```

All I get when I try to open the Swagger after deploying it in the ISS is a blank page and a 500 internal server error, which doesn't say the exception.

Here is my Configure method (startup.cs)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
        }
        else
        {
            // To deploy on IIS
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/SimulaFrete/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API V1");
        }

    });
}
```

and here's my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1",

      new OpenApiInfo
      {

          Title = "Simulador de frete por Unidade",
          Version = "v1",
          Description = "Métodos da API de simulação de frete",
          Contact = new OpenApiContact
          {
              Name = "Catalde Technology",
              Url = new Uri("https://www.catalde.com"),
              Email = "cicero.catalde@catalde.com"
          }
      });

        string caminhoAplicacao =
            PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        string nomeAplicacao =
            PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationName;
        string caminhoXmlDoc =
            Path.Combine(caminhoAplicacao, $"{nomeAplicacao}.xml");

        c.IncludeXmlComments(caminhoXmlDoc);
        c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First()); //This line
    });
}
```

And there's my Controller code which has only this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Post([FromBody]dadosFrete xml)
{
    // code logic
}
```

Comment: try this for .NET 7
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058563/publishing-web-api-with-swagger-on-iis/75087754#75087754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058563/publishing-web-api-with-swagger-on-iis/75087754#75087754)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to temporarily add the production clause in your condition before you can see the swagger in the production environment. See the yellow highlighted section in the attached image. **env.IsProduction()**

[image]

Comment: You didnt add the image correctly, use ![description](link) instead

Comment: It works to me      if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsProduction()), thanks

Comment: This answer just made me feel like a flipping idiot well spoted why on earth does boiler plate code add it here.

Comment: it works for me in Net6 minimal API

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() **|| app.Environment.IsProduction())**
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

Comment: I would put the UseSwagger and UseSwaggerUI outside of the condition and not put things in the condition that is related to development.  Since the us of swagger is necessary for both environment there's no reason to add both statement in the if

Comment: after change working for me... if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsProduction())

Comment: I thought of deploying in debug mode, but that didn't work... Does that mean these are 2 different things to consider ?

Answer (score 11):

Try this. To set relative path.

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
});
```

if this solution not work.
Then check publish setting. The issue is that running **dotnet publish** with **-r Release** does not produce XML file. However, **dotnet publish** with **-r Debug** does in fact produce the file. This explains why people are only getting this issue when they are deploying to environments OTHER than locally.
You can simplify find out in **Project > Your Project properties > Build Tab**

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This makes your answer much more useful to those who come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me. I was able to get it working locally on IIS.

1. You'll need to publish the project to a folder and point IIS to that folder.
2. Edit the Configure method and move out Swagger out of env.IsDevelopment and use vipul's solution above to fix the path.

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
 }
 app.UseSwagger();
 app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
   string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
   c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API");

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to use [multiple environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in .net core.
Some options are

- using a `launch.json` file for your different environments (dev/stage/prod) (local dev only)
- Adding an environment variable named `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with `development`, `stage` or `production`
- Or making a `web.config` to deploy to IIS and add the value

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For IIS, it all depends on the version of IIS. Older versions of IIS, I believe you can only go with web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it is top ranking in Google for this issue.
None of the above worked for me.I wasn't getting a 500 (or a 404), just a blank Swagger page. I could also open swagger.json OK
My real problem was that the Sys Admins don't allow anything other than IE on a server here, so I was testing my deployment (before they had opened the firewall ports) locally using IE.
Swagger page opens, but displays nothing in IE.
Bending the rules, I installed Edge and swagger was working fine.
Hope this saves someone else a wasted morning.

Answer (score 1):

I spent several days troubleshooting. it turned out if I publish in x86 the page displays just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Simply edit your csproj file and add the following snippet

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
 <EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```