# Publishing web api with swagger on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying figure out how to publish a .net core 3 API with Swagger (SwashBuckle) after following this example [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) . So it works locally and when I hit F5 IIS Express launches the site under `http://localhost:8033/index.html`

Here is the Configure code in startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.ContentRootPath),
                RequestPath = new PathString("")
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
                c.DocumentTitle = "TestAPI";
                c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;                   
            });                
        }
```

Next I published the API to a local folder and copied the files to the IIS folder on the server. If I open the server API domain I get a `page can’t be found`. Which address should I use to open up the swagger UI on the server? Is something missing from the configuration?

Comment: Refer

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Open `applicationHost.config` and locate the XML elements for this new site. Paste them as part of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no problem with your `Swagger` settings. Please don’t forget configure the `Swagger` generator, as well as the comments path for the `Swagger JSON`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "ToDo API",
                    Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API",
                    TermsOfService = new Uri("https://example.com/terms"),
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Name = "Shayne Boyer",
                        Email = string.Empty,
                        Url = new Uri("https://twitter.com/spboyer"),
                    },
                    License = new OpenApiLicense
                    {
                        Name = "Use under LICX",
                        Url = new Uri("https://example.com/license"),
                    }
                });
                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
        }
```

Besides, Please ensure that the server has installed the Asp.net core hosting bundle on the sever-side.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamQian thanks for your explanation. I have all the code in place and the API is working that is I am able to trigger a REST call from a client. However the SwaggerUI isn´t shown on the server. I assume it should be enough to point to the index.html like this http://MyServerAPI/index.html ? Even though there are no static files or wwwroot folder located in the project I assume the Swagger will generate this on the fly?

Comment: yes, the URL is enough to navigate the SwaggerUI. But I am not sure about the second question. You could try to configure in the CSPROJ file to allow the compiler to generate a file , just like the document said.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we're using ASP.NET Core / 7 for building the web api.
For .NET 7 (or minimal api) we need to try commenting / adjusting the snippet below in Program.cs

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
//}
```

Next build / publish using VS / VS Code
And access your API on local dev / test:
https://local-api.{yur-api-name}.com/{service-name}Services/swagger/index.html

Comment: This resolved it for me. Thanks! I had specific code around those two lines, only for when in Development environment. Removed the restriction and works like a charm

Comment: Thanks a million. my problem has been resolved by this answer. I didn't know how to publish my swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Startup.cs File

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/index.html");
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");

            // custom CSS
            c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
        });

        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
            {
                ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
            }
        });


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseCors();

    }
```

https://youtu.be/6HiaXCAlRr0

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, it could also be possible that the following nodes are missing from the API project file under the PropertyGroup node.

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
```